# Does Ruby have atomic variables?

Tags: ruby

Does Ruby have atomic variables, like `AtomicInteger` or `AtomicBoolean` in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here is a gem](http://github.com/headius/ruby-atomic) that might provide what you need (found [linked from here](http://moonbase.rydia.net/mental/blog/programming/atomic-operations-in-ruby.html)). [The code is clean and compact enough to quickly understand](https://github.com/headius/ruby-atomic/blob/master/lib/atomic.rb) (it is basically a Mutex, as everyone else has suggested), which should give you a good starting point if you want to write your own Mutex wrapper.

A lightly modified example from [github](http://github.com/headius/ruby-atomic):

```
require 'atomic'

my_atomic = Atomic.new('')

# set method 1:
my_atomic.update { |v| v + 'hello' }

# set method 2:
begin
  my_atomic.try_update { |v| v + 'world' }
rescue Atomic::ConcurrentUpdateError => cue
  # deal with it (retry, propagate, etc)
end

# access with:
puts my_atomic.value
```

Answer (score 8):

It should be noted that implementing atomic types in terms of mutexes defeats the purpose of using the 'atomic' abstraction.

Proper atomic implementations emit code that leverages CPU's compare-and-swap instruction.

Answer (score 5):

Use Mutex as suggested like so:

```
i = 0
lock = Mutex.new

# Then whenever you want to modify it:
lock.synchronize do
  i += 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Ruby has one. However, there is a [Mutex](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Mutex.html) you can use to imitate one.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, but you can get some atomicity using the [`Mutex`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Mutex.html) class.

You could probably implement your own `AtomicString`, for example, using a `Mutex`.